# Unable to re-borrow a variable because I cannot borrow immutable local variable as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust and have my difficulties with the borrow checker.

Calling `consume_byte` from `main` works just fine. But if I try to add another function (`consume_two_bytes`) in between it all falls apart.

The following code won't compile since it seems like the `reader` variable in `consume_two_bytes` is not mutable and cant be borrowed.

Adding a `&mut` in the function signature just changes the compiler error.

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn consume_byte<R>(reader: R) where R: Read {
    let mut buffer = vec![];
    reader.take(1).read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
}

fn consume_two_bytes<R>(reader: R) where R: Read {
    consume_byte(&mut reader);
    consume_byte(&mut reader);
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    let (mut stream, _) = listener.accept().unwrap();

    consume_byte(&mut stream);
    consume_byte(&mut stream);

    consume_two_bytes(&mut stream);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reader` has to be mutable in `consume_two_bytes`:

```
fn consume_two_bytes<R>(mut reader: R) where R: Read { // note the mut
    consume_byte(&mut reader);
    consume_byte(&mut reader);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It never crossed my mind to use `mut` without `&`. That was some serious tunnel vision on my end.

Comment: @DonaldH Yeah, the `mut` being in different places is a bit unintuitive.

Comment: It's unintuitive until you get used to it, then it becomes intuitive again ^_^. Many people point out that the syntax mirrors that of `let` bindings / pattern bindings.

Comment: Note that it happens to work in this case because there is `impl<'a, R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &'a mut R` (i.e. a mutable reference to a type that implements `Read` also implements `Read`). This is not necessarily the case for other traits.